# Gitlab showing draft commit when i revert branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a task branch. I uploaded it to the release branch, but then I did a reverse in the gitlab interface. Revert merge request. Now I want to push this branch back to the release branch.

But Gitlab shows the draft commit. Shows diff empty

Why is that? there are definitely no changes in the release branch

If you do a reset, then everything is fine, I also compared the files and functionality, there really are no changes in the release one, but why the gitlab shows that there are no changes is unclear